# How do I configure mongodb replicaset using elastic IP's in EC2?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2

tldr: What will I need to do in order to use an elastic IP in my MongoDB replicaset configuration?

We have a three-node MongoDB replicaset running on EC2. One of the instances in the set was  retired by AWS yesterday, and so we were forced to stop and restart the EC2 instance.

Unfortunately, when we first configured the replicaset, we were fairly new to AWS and not aware that the public DNS address of the instances was subject to change. We used the public DNS of each instance in the replicaset configuration, and in all of the application connection strings in our code. After reading up on the subject yesterday, I tried to get the node back online by assigning an elastic IP to the instance and changing the replicaset configuration to use that IP. After some pain, I was able to get the other two nodes back up and running with that configuration, but the instance with the elastic IP refused to re-join the replicaset, and the error in mongod.log says:

```
[rsStart] replSet info self not present in the repl set configuration
```

After yet *more* reading, I found that I should not have used the actual elastic IP in the config, but rather the public DNS name of the elastic IP. My question is, before I take everything offline again to try this change, **what exactly will I need to do in order to use the elastic IP in the replicaset configuration**? I found some information on this 10Gen page: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/#communication-across-regions that made me think I might need to mess with the hostname of the instance and/or the hosts file, but I haven't been able to find anybody describing my exact scenario.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be a pretty simple fix; once I changed the replicaset configuration to use the public DNS of the elastic IP, the mongo node came back online. I didn't have to touch the hostname or the hosts file.

Comment: This also resolves to the internal private IP so you aren't charged for external traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use an Elastic IP for internal traffic like replication. You will be charged $0.01/GB for this traffic, whereas using the internal IP would be free.

If you're using something like replica sets, you really should be running in a VPC. Unlike normal EC2 instances, instances in an VPC keep the same private IP addresses and Elastic IP addresses even when stopped.

Comment: You can connect with the public DNS, within the region, it will resolve to an internal IP.

Comment: @datasage Yes, but as the OP noted, the public DNS can change if you stop the instance. VPC fixes this by ensuring static internal IPs that can be used to set up stuff like replication, as well as automatically re-attaching EIPs.

Comment: @ceejayoz What datasage was talking about is the public DNS of the Elastic IP - that gives you the best of both: it is static, but it resolves to the internal IP within the same region. I agree that VPC would alleviate this problem, but it wasn't an option when we launched, and moving to a VPC would be a project in and of itself.